Can I use IDENTITY_INSERT on a table referenced by a SYNONYM?
I can't find anything that says I cannot do this, but if I use INSERT_IDENTITY on a table, referenced by a synonym, I get error:

'MyOtherDB.MyTable' is not a user table. Cannot perform SET operation.

The error is raised on the INSERT_IDENTITY statement (both the ON and the OFF)
Synonym was created like this (and a schema for MyOtherDB before that):
CREATE SYNONYM MyOtherDB.MyTable
FOR MyOtherDB.dbo.MyTable

This works just fine:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyOtherDB.dbo.MyTable ON

and the subsequent INSERT, even using the SYNONYM rather than 3-part-naming, works just fine.
But this fails
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyOtherDB.MyTable ON

I suspect that this is not permitted, but I would like to know that for definite before I give up.
We copy the database from PRODUCTION to DEV and because the physical database names are different we just adjust the synonyms and everything works fine on DEV server, so it will be a nuisance if the IDENTITY ON/OFF has to use hardcoded 3-part naming. I could probably work around it with dynamic SQL, but that will be a bit of a nuisance too.
To clarify: the underlying table is definitely a physical table, not a view etc.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT is not one of the documented places a synonym can be used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#using-synonyms
